# Extracting JSON values using Python

Tags: python, json, firebase

I currently have a script running to read a JSON text file and I want to output the values in a specific format.

My output in firebase looks like this:

```
Value:
 0: "{'status': 'success'"
 1: " 'country': 'Malaysia'"
 2: " 'countryCode': 'MY'"
 3: " 'region': '10'"
 4: " 'regionName': 'Selangor'"
 5: " 'city': 'Kajang'"
 6: " 'zip': '43007'"
 7: " 'lat': 2.9927"
 8: " 'lon': 101.7909"
 9: " 'timezone': 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur'"
 10: " 'isp': 'Tmnet"
 11: " Telekom Malaysia Bhd.'"
 12: " 'org': 'Adsl Streamyx'"
 13: " 'as': 'AS4788 Tmnet"
 14: " Telekom Malaysia Bhd.'"
 15: " 'query': '175.136.0.3'}"
```

I just want it to have it like this (without the double quotes and brackets)

```
Value:
 0: status: success
 1: country: Malaysia
 2: countryCode: MY
 3: region: 10
 4: regionName: Selangor
 5: city: Kajang
 6: zip: 43007
 7: lat: 2.9927
 8: lon: 101.7909
 9: timezone: Asia/Kuala_Lumpur
 10: isp: Tmnet Telekom Malaysia Bhd.
 11: org: Adsl Streamyx
 12: as: AS4788 Tmnet
 13: Telekom Malaysia Bhd.
 14: query: 75.136.0.3
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Post each dictionary in the JSON? Why the splitting? For those of us who aren't familiar with firebase, it's going to take an actual explanation of the output format.

Answer (score 0):

from my experience,python and json never mix well...
If ou want a cheap solution to this problem, use `replace()` and put every char you don't want in it. Like this :

```
from firebase import firebase
import json
import time
conn=firebase.FirebaseApplication('myURL', None)

while True:
    with open('ipinfotest.txt') as f:
        for obj in json.load(f):
            c=f"{obj['values']}"
            d=c.split(",")
            data_2={
                "Value": d.replace("'","").replace("{","").replace("}","")
            }
            print(data_2)
            result=conn.post('IpInfo',data_2)
    f.close()
```

Probably some way cleaner options, but it should works

Comment: im getting an error
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am sorry to say but the way you have written your code is horrible.

Please note these points:

1) Why are you running an infinity loop and reading again and again from the file?

2) You are basically depending on the conn.post() to throw an exception and after that, your script will get closed. Which interns will never be exit(0) exit from the program.

Now, coming to the solution:

Since you are already reading the JSON as dictionary here `json.load(f)` then why bother to split the string and set value?

Simply iterate over the dictionary, read `key` and `value`. Accordingly, send whatever you want to send to the firebase. That will automatically be without the double quotes and brackets.

I am writing the algorithm below and I would like you to write the code yourself:

- Read JSON from the file.
- convert that JSON to a dictionary in python.
- Iterate over the dictionary and send data accordingly.
- close file connection.
- close firebase connection.